# How do I make a drill hole the same depth every time?

Tags: technique, power-tools, drilling, drill-bits

My drill press doesn't have a "stop".

How do I make a drill hole the same depth every time?

Comment: I would be interested in a picture or model number for your drill press.

Comment: I believe its this one RYOBI Model # DP102L.

Comment: Page 21 of the manual shows that this model includes a depth stop and how to adjust it: http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/pdfImages/6d/6d1eec48-c004-451d-a647-978ea2cc66e3.pdf

Comment: Good grief man - that is exciting. I just checked my documentation and that is indeed the model. 100's of people have been using this drill press for several years and never noticed this. I am used to seeing a different style. Next time I'm in the shop, I will see if the knob is broken off or something.

Comment: This is an opiion question there will be a lot of opinions about how to do this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The simplest means is to place a tab of masking tape on the drill bit at the desired depth.  When the spinning tab lowers to the surface of the wood and sweeps away the wood chips, stop.

Comment: When using this technique, make sure that the tape is securely wrapped around the bit. The tape can slide up the bit and make you drill deeper than you intended. As a precaution, check the position of the tape after every few holes to make sure that it remains consistent.

Comment: when my brother showed me this trick, he put the tape on the drill bit, then slid the bit into the chuck until the tape stopped it.  presto: no tape slipping.

Comment: Also make sure that the tape is applied in the "spin" direction, so that it doesn't come undone just from the drill's spin

Answer (score 41):

Ashler's answer is the simplest and cheapest way to get holes the same depth.  But as an extra there are bit collars that can be put on the bits which will enforce exact depth stops.

[image]

Comment: Ah ... great minds think alike

Comment: @Matt  Yes!  And you beat me to the punch because my image links weren't working!  :)

Comment: You seemed to have come out on top of this as well.

Comment: I'm surprised!  I think it was mostly luck...

Comment: These are the good sort.  Some cheap stops have a grubscrew trying and sometimes failing to grip the drill bit.  Get the good sort if you can.

Comment: @NipFu On the drill tang coming out of housing when drilling  make a two red marks when first drilling to maximum depth. Go fast up to first mark, then slowly up to  second.

Comment: These stops work, however, care needs to be taken that the stop does not touch the surface of the wood since it can leave marks. To reduce the risk of leaving marks, cover the area you are drilling with a piece of masking tape first.

Comment: @JasonHutchinson Another way I like to do that is hold a piece of scrap wood (of consistent thickness) on top and drill through it.

Comment: For those in Europe, Wolfcraft sells such items. Search for "wolfcraft 2751000" and see which provider is close and acceptable to you.

Answer (score 38):

A lot of people drill a hole through a suitable length of wood dowel (or small square cross section) and use that as a stop-collar on the drill.

[image]

[Example](http://www.rpwoodwork.com/blog/2015/04/21/is-there-a-good-drill-stop-out-there/)

You can also just use an external chunk of wood

[image]

[Example](https://woodgears.ca/workbench/drawers.html)

One benefit of both these is you don't need an Allen key and can very quickly swap back and forth between two or more different depths (useful for e.g. dowelling)

Unlike some pieces of tape or rubber/plastic grommets, they can't be pushed out of position by overenthusiastic pressure.

Answer (score 22):

You can also adjust your drill press table to be at the desired depth when the drill reaches the end of it's stroke.

Comment: This is also an elegant solution which I never considered. I suppose the repeat-ability also depends on the quality of the drill press table (which don't always lock down well on cheaper ones) whereas the tape or depth-stop collars are accurate regardless. But still, this is an interesting technique as it is less dependent on eye-balling than the tape and less expensive than the collars.

Comment: It also won't mar the surface like the collars will.

Answer (score 17):

Tape is what I would have suggested and continue to use but if you wanted something a little more robust my suggestion would be depth stop collars /nuts

[image]

<sup>Image from [AliExpress](http://ru.aliexpress.com/store/product/8pcs-Drill-Bit-Depth-Stop-Collar-Split-Ring-Woodworking-Drills-Clamping-Device-Positioner-Hole-Drill-Press/932790_2032105647.html?storeId=932790)</sup>

Easily removed off the bits and adjustable as well which tape would not be as much.

Comment: I think I lucked out in getting a picture of higher quality depth stops...

Comment: For sure. I didnt find the one I really wanted  and settled :(

Comment: Still made it to 10!

Comment: Well I already upvoted this one last night.

Comment: @Matt you will make 10K

Comment: @Matt be happy. and celebrate.

Answer (score 0):

if this is not a big project and you're just trying to get very close sized holes..  (maybe you don't want to punch through the other side),  i've used electrical tape on the drill bit.  just tape above the depth you want to stop.  when you hit the tape...  stop...

Comment: I was about to post this exact solution.

Comment: I don't think electrical tape, over the accepted answer's masking tape, warrants its own answer.

Comment: Agree with @Mazura